# Terraform: list to string

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a Security Group using terraform module `terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws`. This would need VPC `id` which is taken from `aws_vpcs` data source. The VPC id requires a string value, but the `aws_vpcs` data source returns a list with a single value.

Please find

```
data "aws_vpcs" "this" {
  tags = {
    "Name" = "example"
  }
}

module "route53_sg" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"

  name        = "R53_health_checkers"
  description = "Security group for Route53 health checkers"
  vpc_id      = element([data.aws_vpcs.this.ids], 0)
  ingress_cidr_blocks = [
...
...
...
  ]
  ingress_rules = ["https-443-tcp"]
}
```

```
$ terraform apply
data.aws_lb.ext_alb: Refreshing state...
data.aws_vpcs.this: Refreshing state...

Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on main.tf line 75, in module "route53_sg":
  75:   vpc_id      = element([data.aws_vpcs.this.ids], 0)

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "vpc_id" defined at
.terraform/modules/route53_sg/terraform-aws-modules-terraform-aws-security-group-d55e4de/variables.tf:10,1-18:
string required.



vpc_id is expecting a Single string. FOLLOWING is a result from Output.tf

$ terraform apply
data.aws_lb.ext_alb: Refreshing state...
data.aws_vpcs.this: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

vpc = [
  "vpc-08067a598522a7b30",
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data.aws_vpcs.this.ids` is already a list, you don't need to put it into another list.

Try:

```
vpc_id = element(data.aws_vpcs.this.ids, 0)
```

---

**EDIT**: Answering questions from the comment:
It seems like the `ids` returned is a set instead of a list, as mentioned in a similar issue here:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7522

If you are using `0.12.x`:
You can do

```
vpc_id = element(tolist(data.aws_vpcs.this.ids), 0)
```

If you are using `0.11.x`: You can do

```
vpc_id = element(split(",", join(",", data.aws_vpcs.this.ids))), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Jackyjjc for your reply
I tried that. Got the following error :

```
Error: Error in function call

  on main.tf line 75, in module "route53_sg":
  75:   vpc_id      = element(data.aws_vpcs.this.ids, 0)
    |----------------
    | data.aws_vpcs.this.ids is set of string with 1 element

Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from set of string.
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the answer to your question

Comment: `vpc_id = element(tolist(data.aws_vpcs.this.ids), 0) ` helped. Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest using `sort(data.aws_vpcs.this.ids)[0]` instead here... the result should be the same, but `sort` makes it explicit that you want to take the first element sorted lexically (though with a single-element set it doesn't really matter) and using [the `element` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/element.html) to access list elements is deprecated in favor of the explicit list index syntax.